# How can addEventListener ignore image and keep getting numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

I have a button that has an image on it and it will be place to another div wherein I'm having no problem with. I'm getting confused with the JS that I followed in a guide. Imagine a button with image and I want it to have a value of number so that when I click submit button, only the number will be acquired by the javascript and database. Below is the js variable declaration:

```
var numbers     = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
var screenSpans = document.querySelectorAll('#screen span');
```

Screen span is where the image will go and number is the class of the button with image and number. In the html, it looks like this:

```
    <div id="screen">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <button class="number">
    <img src="img/1.png" />1
    </button>
```

you will notice that I added "1" just to try if it will work but the submit button is not working whenever i have the `<img src="img/1.png" />` inside the button tags. Everything is perfectly fine without the img but I need to have image in replacement of numbers. In short, I just want the image to be when clicked it will go to screen span and the javascript and database will read the number instead. How can my javascript ignore the image? Below are the important js that I used:

```
for (var i = numbers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    numbers[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        reset = 0;
        nextSpan(this.innerHTML);
    });
};
function nextSpan (currNumber){
    for (var i = 0; i < screenSpans.length; i++) {
        if (screenSpans[i].innerHTML == '' && reset == 0){
            screenSpans[i].innerHTML = currNumber;
            reset = 1;
        }
    };
}
```

Will appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use the data-* attribute i.e <button class='number' data-number='1'>...</button> then use the jQuery attr method for retrieving the value?

Comment: thank you! forgot that sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your `form` element create a hidden input element (e.g. `<input type="hidden" name="prop" value="2" />`); you can set the value of this hidden input as you please (e.g. when you click on an image). If you want your image to supply the number, then for each image you could set a custom attribute (e.g. `data-img-num="2"`) and set that as the hidden input's value when that specific image is clicked. For example:

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="prop" value="0" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<div class="imgContainer">
   <img src="" data-img-num="1" />
   <img src="" data-img-num="2" />
</div>
```

**jQuery etc.**

```
$('.imgContainer > [data-img-num]').on('click', function() {
    $('form input[name="prop"]').val($(this).attr('data-img-num'));
});
```

Something like that should do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<input type="text">` and `<label>` elements. Set `appearance` `input type="text"` element `style` attribute to `appearance:button`; `value` attribute to `1`;  `maxlength` to `0`; `name` to appropriate name for the element within the `<form>`. At `css` set `background-image` of element, at `:hover` pseudo element set `cursor` to `pointer`.

Substitute `<label>` elements for `<span>` elements. At `click` at `.number` element, iterate `input type="text"` `.labels`, set `.innerHTML` to `.value` of `input type="text"` element.

At `click` of `input type="text"` element iterate `.labels` associated with `input.number` element, set `label` `.innerHTML` to `.value` of `input type="text"` element.

At `submit` of `form` the the `.name`, `.value` pair of the `input type="text'` element will be submitted.

```css
#screen > input[type="text"].number {
  display:block;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics"); /*"img/1.png"*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: transparent;
}

#screen > input[type="text"].number:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form action="/path/to/server/" method="POST">

  <div id="screen">
    <label for="image"></label>
    <label for="image"></label>
    <label for="image"></label>
    <input type="text" 
           id="image" 
           class="number"
           name="number" 
           value="1"            
           maxlength="0" 
           style="appearance:button;width:50px;height:50px;" />
    <!-- border:none;outline:none; -->
    <!--
    <button class="number">
    <img src="img/1.png" />1
    </button>
   -->
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
</form>
<script>
  document.querySelector("#screen > .number")
  .addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    for (let label of event.target.labels) {
          label.innerHTML = event.target.value;
    }
  });
</script>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qzeyc3jL/

Comment: I used this technique but not in my project, but anyway I just changed the whole content and now it's perfectly fine. Thank you so much!